# python 3.X if statements

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that asks from the user to get input that equal to only one word (a-z)- my  requirements :

If the user entered a string of letters that has more than one character, print the string "E1" on the screen.

If the user entered a character that is not an English letter (for example, a sign such as: &, *), print the string "E2" on the screen.

If the user entered a string of letters that contains more than one death and also contains characters that are not letters in English, print the string "E3" on the screen

I am trying this code :

```
Word = input(('Please choice word:\n'))
if Word == 'a''b':
    print("good")
else:
    print("not good")
```

but is seems me that the code is too long and clumsy.

Comment: what is "more than one death"?

Comment: what if for `a1` and `a`?

Comment: Try using Word.isalpha(). This checks if a string contains only letters

Answer (score 2):

```
Word = input(('Please choice word:\n'))

specialChars = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

if(Word in specialChars ):
    print("E2")
    
else:
    for char in Word:
        if(char in specialChars):
            print("E3")
            break
    print("E1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. I still don't know what `more than one death` means.

```
wd = input ('Please choice word:\n')

if len(wd) > 1: #first check if the length of the word is one character
    if not (all((a.isalpha() or a ==' ') for a in wd)):
        print ('E3') #if more than one char and if any of them are special chars, then E3
    else:
        print ('E1') #if more than one char but word is ([a-z] or [A-Z])
elif not wd.isalpha(): #check if letter is [a-z] or [A-Z]. if not, then E2
    print ('E2')
```

The output for this will be:

```
Please choice word:
Good
E1
Please choice word:
B@d
E3
Please choice word:
@
E2
Please choice word:
Good Day
E1
Please choice word:
B
```

The last one does not print anything in response as it meets all the criteria.